# Proving statements about Killing vector fields

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, vector-fields

I'm proving some identities on Killing vectors and the like and I've stumbled on this one which I can't seem to figure out.

Suppose $A^\mu = K^\mu$ is a Killing vector and we have the following field $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$. I want to show that $$g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\mu F_{\nu\rho} = 0.$$

I've tried writing out the covariant derivative. I've tried writing out the field $F_{\mu\nu}$ and using the Killing equation, but that just leads to an expression for the Ricci tensor. Lastly I've also tried using the Bianchi identity, but this just resulted in the fact that $F_{\mu\nu}$ is anti-symmetric in its indices.

Any tips/help to put me on track is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure about this identity? $\nabla_aK_b=\nabla_{[a}K_{b]}$ due to killing equation, but this is same as $F_{ab}$. So the expression doesn't depend on any particular choice of $A^a$. What you are trying to show is that $\nabla^aF_{ab}=0$ is an identity... but that is not true... Recall Maxwell's equation in presence of a source

Comment: @KP99 doublechecked and this is the correct statement I found in my notes. Maybe there I made an error writing it down; any idea on what the correct statement would be?

Comment: I guess, eqn (12),(13) and (14) from [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KillingVectors.html#:~:text=If%20any%20set%20of%20points,is%20called%20a%20Killing%20vector.) should be relevant for you